# Is there a shorten formed of the name for Polish złoty?

Tags: names

The name for the Polish currency złoty is this in Chinese:

> [波兰兹罗提](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B3%A2%E5%85%B0%E5%85%B9%E7%BD%97%E6%8F%90)

Most currencies also have abbreviations. The obviously inapplicable shortened form would be:

- 波罗

Possible contractions might include:

- 波兹
- 波提

I haven't been able to find any usage of either of those two though. Is there a shorten formed of the name for Polish złoty?

Comment: "兹罗提" is fine since only Poland is using it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a universal shorten form for names.

**The initial + kind.**

兹币(兹罗提)

盖氏(比尔 盖茨)

赤国(赤道几内亚)

青刀(青龙偃月刀)

And the damned 蛇果(红地厘蛇果)

Comment: Not seeing any usage of 兹币 or 波兹 by association.

Comment: @user3306356 Yeah, cuz it doesn't need to be shortened at all. The name is not long, and only 1 character is saved, and the first one 兹币(兹罗提) cost more characters.